# Semantic-UI - Themes - Build Failing

Tags: css, frontend, semantic-ui

I am trying to configure a theme in Semantic-UI

I am using the `version 1.8.1`

I changed the following two lines in `theme.config` folder

```
/* Global */
@site       : 'material';
@reset      : 'material';
```

And then i attempted a gulp clean and gulp build but the process gives me an error

```
D:\Installers\Semantic-UI\Semantic-UI-1.8.1>gulp clean
[15:44:00] Using gulpfile D:\Installers\Semantic-UI\Semantic-UI-1.8.1\gulpfile.js
[15:44:00] Starting 'clean'...
[15:44:00] Finished 'clean' after 64 ms

D:\Installers\Semantic-UI\Semantic-UI-1.8.1>gulp build
[15:44:31] Using gulpfile D:\Installers\Semantic-UI\Semantic-UI-1.8.1\gulpfile.js
[15:44:31] Starting 'build'...
Building Semantic
[gulp] Created: dist\components\site.js
[15:44:36] Plumber found unhandled error:
 Error in plugin 'gulp-less'
Message:
    'themes//material/globals/reset.variables' wasn't found in file D:\Installers\Semantic-UI\Semantic-UI-1.8.1\src\theme.l
ess line no. 19
Details:
    type: File
    filename: D:\Installers\Semantic-UI\Semantic-UI-1.8.1\src\theme.less
    index: 420
    line: 19
    callLine: NaN
    callExtract: undefined
    column: 0
    extract: @import "@{themesFolder}/@{site}/globals/site.variables";,@import "@{themesFolder}/@{theme}/@{type}s/@{element
}.variables";,
    lineNumber: 19
    fileName: D:\Installers\Semantic-UI\Semantic-UI-1.8.1\src\theme.less
[gulp] Created: dist\components\site.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\form.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\form.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\form.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\flag.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\flag.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\form.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\accordion.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\accordion.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\checkbox.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\site.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\site.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\dimmer.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\button.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\checkbox.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\button.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\dropdown.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\dimmer.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\divider.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\divider.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\modal.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\dropdown.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\header.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\header.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\nag.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\modal.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\icon.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\icon.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\popup.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\nag.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\image.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\image.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\progress.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\popup.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\input.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\rating.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\input.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\progress.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\search.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\rating.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\label.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\label.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\shape.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\search.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\list.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\shape.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\list.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\sidebar.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\loader.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\sticky.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\loader.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\sidebar.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\rail.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\sticky.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\tab.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\rail.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\transition.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\tab.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\reveal.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\reveal.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\video.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\transition.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\segment.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\segment.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\api.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\video.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\step.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\step.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\state.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\api.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\breadcrumb.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\breadcrumb.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\state.min.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\visibility.js
[gulp] Created: dist\components\form.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\visibility.min.js
[15:45:12] Starting 'package compressed js'...
[15:45:13] Starting 'package uncompressed js'...
[gulp] Created: dist\components\form.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\form.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\form.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\grid.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\grid.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\menu.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\menu.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\message.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\message.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\table.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\table.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\ad.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\ad.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\card.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\card.css
[gulp] Created: dist\semantic.js
[15:45:44] Finished 'package uncompressed js' after 31 s
[gulp] Created: dist\semantic.min.js
[15:45:44] Finished 'package compressed js' after 31 s
[gulp] Created: dist\components\comment.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\comment.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\feed.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\feed.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\item.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\item.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\statistic.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\statistic.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\accordion.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\accordion.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\checkbox.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\checkbox.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\dimmer.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\dimmer.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\dropdown.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\dropdown.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\modal.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\modal.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\nag.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\nag.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\popup.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\popup.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\progress.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\progress.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\rating.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\rating.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\search.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\search.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\shape.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\shape.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\sidebar.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\sidebar.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\sticky.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\sticky.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\tab.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\tab.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\transition.min.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\transition.css
[gulp] Created: dist\components\video.min.css
[15:45:52] Finished 'build' after 1.33 min
[15:45:52] Starting 'package compressed css'...
[gulp] Created: dist\components\video.css
[15:45:52] Starting 'package uncompressed css'...
[gulp] Created: dist\semantic.min.css
[15:46:41] Finished 'package compressed css' after 49 s
[gulp] Created: dist\semantic.css
[15:46:41] Finished 'package uncompressed css' after 49 s
```

I have 3 questions

1. Does this mean that I cannot use whatever is generated in the dist
   folder?
2. Is this error due to incomplete/missing files in the theme
   folder? I see that many of them don't have the site.variables
3. Where can i download the additional themes from?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. What I did then was copying the `reset.overrides` and `reset.variables` form the **themes/default** into **themes/metarial**

after running gulp build afterwards, I had no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I continued to get errors that the themes/material/collections, themes/material/elements directories and/or files were not found, so I just copied all of the directories and files (collections/[all files], etc.) into the material theme and it ran fine and finally compiled all the .css files.